# how to compare different versions of Matlab on different machines similar to bench() functions?

Tags: performance, matlab

So matlab has a set of tools to check if the processor and setting of computer is good enough and how it ranks to popular settings. its a range of matrix based tests(LU,FFT,ODE,SPARSE,2D,3D)

However, according to matlab here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bench.html
Note:   "A benchmark is intended to compare performance of one particular version of MATLAB on different machines. It does not offer direct comparisons between different versions of MATLAB because tasks and problem sizes change from version to version."

So is there any set of problems or similar package that can compare between machines who use different versions of Matlab? or what is the best way to compare different versions of Matlab on different machine? is there any universal benchmark that can provide a bigger picture?

The goals is focused on mostly vector based numerical operation with no graphic  and no graphical animation. My university cloud based Matlab version is very different from our desktop version or my personal version on laptop.

Comment: Typically this would involve running the code that you want to run. It's going to vary depending on what you want your code to do.

Comment: I hope just like bench() from mathworks, there is way to check different machines who have different versions.

Comment: It's called `timeit` or `tic`/`toc` to time your code. As I said, the performance depends on what you are trying to do. Your best bet is to benchmark your own code.

Comment: This is a great question—what’s with all you downvoters?

Comment: Other than the straightforward answer—write your own open-source benchmark that exercises LU, FFT, ODE, etc., in *very specific ways* for a wide range of problem sizes—I don’t know of anything special. Matlab *should* have a function like `bench` that stays constant across Matlab versions, and very likely `bench` changes very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

You may rename the module bench and then run it in different Matlab versions.This will undo any changes that Mathworks apparently applies to bench.m.

We have just done this for the Matlab versions that our customers use:

Procedure:

-1- copy "c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\general\bench.m" to "mybench.m"

-2- run "mybench.m" subsequentlty in 2012a (32 bit), 2013a (64 bit), 2016a (64 bit). This runs 5 repetitions of the benchmark.

Date:

August 15, 2016

Results:

Matlab 2012a (32 bit)

LU          FFT          ODE        Sparse    2-D          3-D

```
0.0525    0.1022    0.0524    0.1203    0.2312    0.6745

0.0602    0.1075    0.0520    0.1276    0.2285    0.6913

0.0646    0.1032    0.0523    0.1119    0.2280    0.6711

0.0546    0.1056    0.0518    0.1120    0.2288    0.6992

0.0539    0.1025    0.0520    0.1165    0.2374    0.7007
```

Matlab 2013a (64 bit)

LU          FFT          ODE        Sparse    2-D          3-D

```
0.0473    0.0729    0.0545    0.0948    0.2308    0.6913

0.0494    0.0778    0.0560    0.1083    0.2502    0.6734

0.0585    0.0767    0.0567    0.0944    0.2184    0.6804

0.0539    0.0754    0.0552    0.0951    0.2188    0.6858

0.0520    0.0761    0.0557    0.0948    0.2257    0.6798
```

Matlab 2014b (64 bit)

LU          FFT          ODE        Sparse    2-D          3-D

```
0.0389    0.0670    0.0729    0.0886    0.7948    0.5959

0.0472    0.0691    0.0739    0.0927    0.7582    0.6114

0.0427    0.0675    0.0737    0.0996    0.7288    0.6271

0.0391    0.0682    0.0740    0.0978    0.7316    0.6303

0.0388    0.0717    0.0751    0.0955    0.7096    0.6469
```

Matlab 2016a (64 bit)

LU          FFT          ODE        Sparse    2-D          3-D

```
0.0712    0.1004    0.0542    0.0888    0.7549    0.6586

0.0823    0.1003    0.0527    0.0892    0.7273    0.6345

0.0816    0.0977    0.0523    0.0885    0.7547    0.6280

0.0842    0.1008    0.0542    0.0954    0.6634    0.6355

0.0837    0.1000    0.0514    0.0919    0.6641    0.6440
```